# Getting java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial while setting wallpaper in Android

Tags: android, bitmap

I have an application of wallpapers where I allow the user to set wallpaper directly from the app. Here I convert http url of image into Bitmap and call `WallpaperManager` class of Android.

Following is code for converting URL to bitmap and setting into `WallpaperManager` bitmap:

```
private void setWallpaper() {
        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
        try {
            Bitmap image = getBitMapFromHttpURL();
            if (image != null) {
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(getBitMapFromHttpURL());
                image.recycle();
                image = null;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to set wallpaper",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        } catch (Exception es) {

        }
    }
```

It fails on this line `wallpaperManager.setBitmap(getBitMapFromHttpURL());` with the following exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider uri content://settings/system from pid=21407, uid=10133 requires android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS, or grantUriPermission()
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
       at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:468)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1190)
       at android.provider.Settings$NameValueTable.putString(Settings.java:843)
       at android.provider.Settings.putString(Settings.java:6792)
       at android.provider.Settings.putString(Settings.java:6717)
       at android.app.WallpaperManager.willSendBroadcat(WallpaperManager.java:1124)
       at android.app.WallpaperManager.setBitmap(WallpaperManager.java:788)
       at com.wallie.WallpaperFullScreenActivity.setWallpaper(WallpaperFullScreenActivity.java:453)
       at com.wallie.WallpaperFullScreenActivity.access$1(WallpaperFullScreenActivity.java:448)
       at com.wallie.WallpaperFullScreenActivity$WallpaperManagerTask.doInBackground(WallpaperFullScreenActivity.java:473)
       at com.wallie.WallpaperFullScreenActivity$WallpaperManagerTask.doInBackground(WallpaperFullScreenActivity.java:1)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:238)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: have you define this permission : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/> in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: yes defined already.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735180/crash-when-i-use-method-setwallpaper-android/26735713#26735713

Comment: how it makes difference if I create object of WallpaperManager at class level to method level in my case

Comment: Try add this permission too : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>

Comment: have you try above permission ?

Comment: Add the permission `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` in manifest file

Comment: havent tried with above permission. Will try with that. Thanks.

Comment: Post your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 5):

The exception you are getting clearly defines you need to add the permission in Manifest.

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider uri content://settings/system from pid=21407, uid=10133 requires android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS, or grantUriPermission()

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Comment: its coming on some device only so what is reason for this permission.

Comment: can you specify on *which device* ??

Comment: 7040n alcatel 4.4.2 Android Version

Comment: [Issue with Kitkat](http://www.beyondpod.com/forum/showthread.php?2235-quot-Permission-denied-quot-errors-during-feed-update-after-Kit-Kat-upgrade&s=6f90813e9932a299d3cb6b2ae3c6c804&p=8984&viewfull=1#post8984)

Answer (score 2):

The logcat is clear:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider uri content://settings/system from pid=21407, uid=10133 requires android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS, or grantUriPermission()
```

So you just need to add this permission in your Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

under application tag.

Hope it helps.

Comment: its coming on some device only so what is reason for this permission.

Comment: @vo12 No idea about the version 4.4.2. May be you can try adding and check on that device.

Comment: @vo12 refer to [this](http://trendblog.net/fix-kitkat-sd-card-write-restriction/) once if gives hint.

Comment: Its very difficult to find device i mentioned to test. I will add permission and release it with next update

Comment: thanks but it will be user specific may be i should catch exception and let user know you dont have rights ?

Comment: @vo12 Yes. may be using try catch around that line. And see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9153850/1777090) for more.

Comment: I have this exception only on Samsungs with Kitkat

Answer (score 1):

Your are missing to add [WRITE_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_SETTINGS) permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

If you dont required Bitmap object longer then directly check from bitamp using getBitMapFromHttpURL instead declare Bitamp object.

```
if (getBitMapFromHttpURL() != null) {
    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(getBitMapFromHttpURL());
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to set wallpaper",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May you forgot to take any of this Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
```

Comment: What is the use of `SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS`