# How to send email to specific email?

Tags: android, email

I have following condition:
[image]

How do I send email to example@mail.com on `submitButton` clicklistener ?

```
submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //how to send email ??

        }
    });
```

Help !

Comment: See similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-to-send-email-from-my-android-application)

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-to-send-email-from-my-android-application ?

Comment: There is only three field recipient email address, subject of email and body of email. When i add above fields such as name, sender email address, did it create any problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its very simple. In your `onClick` method simply create and populate the following `Intent`

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Email:"));
```

Comment: Can i add sender emailaddress like   `emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, senderEmailAddress);  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, senderName); `  to this ??

Comment: NO! because `android.content.intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT` specifies the **Subject** of the email

Comment: If you want to specify the name and email address of the recipient you could try using a string like such: `"John Smith <john@smith.com>"`.  I haven't tried it so I don't know if it works, but it should only take you a few seconds to try and see if it works

Comment: Thanx buddies,now I get it, i will try my best, if any problem, i will report to u guys.

Comment: Cant i directly send mail by clicking submit button only without opening default mail client ?

Comment: @captainpirate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-a

Comment: from the refrence u given, i am able to send mail without launching built mail application of android by clicking send button.**But i have to provide gmail authientciation there, can't i remove that part ??** or there any way to fetch gmail username and password from default gmail app ??

Comment: If you don't have access to the gmail credentials then you'll have to provide credentials for "some" account, and NO you can't retrieve them without the users approval.

Comment: Why not use web form instead of an email?

Comment: dont have any idea about web form ?? can u reference me to some good tuts ?