# How do i remove gmail authentication ?

Tags: android, email

I have the following layout : 
[image]

And following code :

```
public class MailSenderActivity extends Activity {
ProgressDialog progress;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send);
    final EditText subjectValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subject);

    final EditText senderEmailValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

    final EditText messageValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(MailSenderActivity.this,
                    "Dialog Title", "Please Wait", true);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        GMailSender sender = new GMailSender(
                                "gmailaddress@gmailcom", "gmailpassword");
                        sender.sendMail(subjectValue.getText().toString(),
                                messageValue.getText().toString(),
                                senderEmailValue.getText().toString(),
                                "targetmailaddress@mail.com");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            progress.dismiss();

                        }
                    });

                }
            }).start();

        }
    });

}
```

}

And

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
private String user;
private String password;
private Session session;

static {
    Security.addProvider(new com.main.JSSEProvider());
}

public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
}

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
}

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body,
        String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
    try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(
                body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setDataHandler(handler);
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
        else
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(recipients));
        Transport.send(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
    private byte[] data;
    private String type;

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        if (type == null)
            return "application/octet-stream";
        else
            return type;
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");
    }
}
```

}

Up to, i am able to send mail on send mail button click with out opening android default mail client.Here it requires gmail verifcation which i dont want.
User just enter subject, email address and message and send mail to target@gmail.com.
I just want to send mail without any mail verfication, also i dont care security risk.
what i have to do? Help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-to-send-email-from-my-android-application

Comment: u r questions and answer very nice i use your code i hava a problem when first time i give username and password run the app it is working fine but problem is when second time i give wrong username and password in this case also it is working, previous values not clear please solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't send mail using Gmail without authenticating. their server, their rules.

Comment: Then i should i fetch gmail username and password to this   `GMailSender sender = new GMailSender(                           "gmailaddress@gmailcom", "gmailpassword");` . I am newbie to this !

Comment: what some developers do is create a gmail account for the purpose of sending messages from applications. this is what I recommend. i.e. use your own credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Well to use the Gmail Service you must require Authantication Code while sending/receiving emails using avove your code. It is for the security purpose from the Gmail Team.

However there is another way of sending email is using the in-bulit email application using the `Intent`.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
i.setType("text/plain"); 
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{ "target@gmail.com"}); 
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject"); 
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body part"); 

try 
{     
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Sending  Email...")); 
} 
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) 
{     
   Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "No Email clients",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show(); 
}
```

Comment: I dont want to use builtin email application. Just want to send mail on clicking send button and all process must carry out in background.

Comment: well in that case you must get authorization code for sending/receiving emails.