# how to check whether email client installed on device

Tags: android

I need to check whether email client is installed on a device or not. I have used the following code but it does not work for me.

```
public boolean isIntentAvailable() {
    final PackageManager packageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "vin@gmail.com");
    List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this, works for me :

```
public static boolean isMailClientPresent(Context context){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/html");
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    if(list.size() == 0)
        return false;
    else 
        return true;
}
```

Comment: This isn't exactly full proof. If you run this using the type as "text/html", it can still find other means that would work other than email. For example, I setup a new emulator and when attempting to call this it shows my list of ResolveInfo objects containing an item via Bluetooth. So, this function call returns true with no email client available. I would recommend that you update this and change the type to "message/rfc822" just as @eyal suggested.

Comment: In my case in `emulator` without Google API support it returns a list with one element (activity "com.android.fallback.Fallback"), then raises an exception when sending an email. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31052350/2914140 for this case.

Answer (score 5):

use this method:

```
    private fun sendEmail(to: Array<String>) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
        intent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:") // only email apps should handle this
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to)
//        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
        if (intent.resolveActivity(requireContext().packageManager) != null) {
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
```

To be able to check for email clients when targeting api 30, add "queries" to the Manifest:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
        <data android:scheme="*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: Thank you! The `<queries>` block is what was missing in my case, and this is the only answer I've found on SO that mentions it. I'm using `packageManager.queryIntentActivities()` to find installed email apps, but on OnePlus devices it was always returning an empty list even if emails apps were installed. I added the `<queries>` block and now it works.

Comment: For the record, after research, the issue I had is not related to OnePlus devices mais to apps targeting SDK >= 30. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64419233/1276306

Answer (score 3):

For email client, specifically,  you should use:

```
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
```

instead of:

```
intent.setType("text/html");
```

Comment: "message/rfc822" results in queryIntentActivities() returning a list.size() of 1 after I delete gmail.  Is there a bulletproof solution to check for installed email client?

Comment: @EdoftheMountain thats sounds coorect, most devices has defualt email client AND gmail. so after you deleted gmail you probably left with defaul one

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to check for email clients on all devices (onePlus, Moto, Samsung etc) is as follows:

In your manifest file you need to add the following code after application tag.

```
<queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <data android:scheme="*" />
        </intent>
</queries>
```

You can replace the scheme as required.
After doing this, you need to use the following code on your button click (or whatever event you have email associated with):

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
email.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"receipient@email.com"});
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Any Subject");
if (email.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)         
    startActivity(email);
else 
   // A toast to display any message when email client is not available
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my way,it is works in xiaomi(android 13) phone:

1. add these in the manifest.xml:

   ```
      <queries>
          <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <data android:scheme="*" />
         </intent>
     </queries>
   ```
2. in the View.OnClickListener's onClick method:

   ```
    val mailIntent = Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(
                           Intent.ACTION_MAIN,
                           Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL
                        )
      mailIntent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")
      val emails = arrayOf(data?.serviceEmail)
      mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emails)
      if (mailIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            startActivity(mailIntent)
      } else {
            showTips("please check whether you have an email app")
      }
   ```