# Why does this Android intent not find an email app?

Tags: android, gmail

I've set up an email intent and tried launching it. Code below:

```
    public void emailSummary(String emailText, String name) {
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "JustJava order for " + name);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailText);
        Log.v("MainActivity", "Finished setting up intent");
        if (emailIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(emailIntent);
            Log.v("MainActivity", "Sharing the order summary to email");
        } else {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "No email app installed!");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uh...No email app?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

However, when I do press the Order button, the "Uh... No email app?" toast shows up. I have both Inbox and Gmail installed, but the `Intent` does not seem to find any of them. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code :

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
        "mailto",name, null));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SOME_SUBJECT");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailText);
try {
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
Log.v("MainActivity", "Sharing the order summary to email");
} 
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
Log.d("MainActivity", "No email app installed!");
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uh...No email app?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

> can you please explain what was wrong with my code?

I've tested your code and `if (emailIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {` is bad to check if there is any email APP on your device. I've found this method and works fine : [`@Nitin answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12617229/4385913)

```
public static boolean isMailClientPresent(Context context){
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/html");
final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

if(list.size() == 0)
    return false;
else 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution! It worked flawlessly and displayed both email apps. And if you have the time, can you please explain what was wrong with my code? Once again, thanks!

Comment: @ideaman924 Check my edit and if it helped to you mark this answer as acorrect :D

Comment: @UncaughtException Thanks ;)

Comment: Mark my answer and upvote it if it was helpful for you :) @ideaman924