# Can i send an e-mail using my application in android

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail

I have developing an application as customer based and each process need to mention to the Customer..

I have set all the designs and functions for my Application, now i need to integrate the Mail functionality to my Application..

Help me, thanks.

Comment: By which type you need to send yours mail..

Comment: By using any Mail-servers like Gmail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following methods..

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
try {
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show);
}
```

and follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-to-send-email-from-my-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

Add Mail.java (class)... i use this example...

```
package com.samples.broadcastreceiver;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
  private String _user; 
  private String _pass; 

  private String[] _to; 
  private String _from; 

  private String _port; 
  private String _sport; 

  private String _host; 

  private String _subject; 
  private String _body; 

  private boolean _auth; 

  private boolean _debuggable; 

  private Multipart _multipart; 


  public Mail() { 
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
    _sport = "465";
    _user = ""; // username 
    _pass = ""; // password 
    _from = ""; // email sent from 
    _subject = ""; // email subject 
    _body = ""; // email body 

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
  } 

  public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
    this(); 

    _user = user; 
    _pass = pass; 
  } 

  public boolean send() throws Exception { 
    Properties props = _setProperties(); 

    if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

      MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

      InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
      } 
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

      msg.setSubject(_subject); 
      msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

      // setup message body 
      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
      messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
      _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

      // Put parts in message 
      msg.setContent(_multipart); 

      // send email 
      Transport.send(msg); 

      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    } 
  } 

  public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
  } 

  private Properties _setProperties() { 
    Properties props = new Properties(); 

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

    if(_debuggable) { 
      props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
    } 

    if(_auth) { 
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
    } 

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

    return props; 
  } 

  // the getters and setters 
  public String getBody() { 
    return _body; 
  } 

  public void setBody(String _body) { 
    this._body = _body; 
  }

public void setSubject(String subj) {
    this._subject = subj;
}

public void setFrom(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this._from= string;

}

public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this._to = toArr;
} 

  // more of the getters and setters ….. 
}
```

Then from activity for example to send mail do just ...

```
public void SendMail() {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Mail m = new Mail("MAIL_ADDRESS@gmail.com", "PASSWORD"); 
    String[] toArr = {GetMailAddress()}; //address to send
    m.setTo(toArr); 
    m.setFrom("MAIL_ADDRESS@gmail.com"); 
    m.setSubject("SUBJECT");         
    m.setBody("BODY");
    try { 
        String path = "/mnt/sdcard/xxxx";
         File fileDir = new File( path );
         if(!fileDir.exists() || !fileDir.isDirectory())
         {
             return;
         }
         String[] _files = fileDir.list(); 
         for ( int i = 0 ; i < _files.length ; i++  )
         { 
               _files[i] = path + "/"+ _files[i];
         }

      m.addAttachment(_files[0]);  

      if(m.send()) { 
    //    Toast.makeText(context, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

        File fileIn = new File(_files[0]);
        boolean deletedIn = fileIn.delete();
      } else { 
     //   Toast.makeText(context, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
      } 
    } catch(Exception e) { 
   //   Toast.makeText(context, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

    }
```

}

Comment: In this ant plug-ins available?

Answer (score 0):

You can send using Intent like this

```
 Intent email_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:")); 
 email_intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject"); 
 email_intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Your Mail Body"); 
 startActivity(email_intent);
```

And  using  the JavaMail API using Gmail authentication
check this one is useful to you.

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124)