# The mp3 files of my app are not sent through gmail

Tags: android

I have a problem, I'm triying to send a mp3 file to gmail.

My code works good so far for whatsapp, hotmail, bluetooth... but it doesn't work with gmail

This is my code:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String path = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/" +"miApp"+"/tono.mp3";

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("audio/mp3");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Asunto");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Prueba");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file:///" + path));
startActivity(intent);
```

I try with various types of mime but with the same results

- "audio/x-mpeg-3"
- "video/mpeg"
- "video/x-mpeg"
- "audio/mpeg"

What's wrong?

Comment: Could this be of any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-to-send-email-from-my-android-application It has slightly different code than yours.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.setType("audio/mp3");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/miApp/tono.mp3"));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: why is it needed in this case?

Comment: It is worked for me and only that part is different. But it cant be related history stack.

Comment: My error is "file unknown file not sent" .I tried to send using bluletooth.How can i rectify these error.please i need your help.