# How to pass registration details via email in android

Tags: android

I am developing one application in that I am sending email, in that there is one registration form and in that some fields are included that is `first_name`, `last_name`, `state`, `phone_number`, `date`, `time` and `phone_number`. So problem is that I have successfully done with email in that to, bcc, cc, subject and message that part I have covered, but I also want the information which I have filled in the registration form, the information should be displayed in the message area in the email.

Comment: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-to-send-email-from-my-android-application/2197841#2197841

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , "receipentEmailId@abc.com");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "add any subject u want");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "<here goes the content like firstName.getText().toString()>"");
```

Comment: thank you charlie, i have done this already...i want to send the registration form information along with Text message.

Comment: @charlie Why you rejected my edit ? Please remove unneeded text "regards Charlie", because it's spam !

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri
                            .fromParts("mailto","abc@mail.com", null));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Your Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Your Content !");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"Send email..."));
```

Comment: Thanks selva, i have clearly mention above, i have done with this, i just want to extra information other than to,bcc,cc,subject,message,attachment in my email. i have mention those fields in problem definition. now waiting for positive reply.

Comment: String content="FirstName :"+firstName.getText().toString()+"\n"+"LastName :"+secName.getText().toString()+"\n"+....... then emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,content);

Comment: thanks selva..but it gives error on getText message, the error is "The method getText() is undefined for the type String"... why it is happend?

Comment: thanks selva i have done it successfully, i have taken all the parameters separately and then i have just concatinate the variables instead of whole. Thanks a lot.

Comment: hi selva....now i want to send simple email using SMTP how to do it. if there is any link or examples you have then please help me...i am waiting...