# Mailto Android: 'Unsupported action' error

Tags: android, email, mobile, mailto

I am new to this but what is wrong with my snippet of coding?
I am getting the error: 'This action is not currently supported' when I select the link.
Here is my code:

```
public void addEmail() {

    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emailtext);

    txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            String uriText =
                    "mailto:youremail@gmail.com" + 
                    "?subject=" + URLEncoder.encode("some subject text here") + 
                    "&body=" + URLEncoder.encode("some text here");

                Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriText);

                Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                sendIntent.setData(uri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send email")); 

    }});

}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-can-i-send-emails-from-my-android-application

Comment: @shkschneider, how does that address the error?

Comment: I ran into this in the Android 4.0.2 emulator when I hadn't set up an email account yet in the Android email client. Setting up an account in the client worked around the problem.

Comment: @Sam Doesn't it explain how to correctly send an email using an `Intent`? It appears the answer below (that you confirmed) goes the same direction. This is how I thought my link addressed the error. My bad if it does not.

Comment: @shkschneider, it does explain how to send emails, but it doesn't really address the actual cause of the "Unsupported action" error. The code in the question actually works fine, but it just breaks in this way in specific circumstances, which, from my testing so far, seem to be a combination of: using an emulator, using `setData`, and the intent not matching anything. The code in this question actually seems better than the `setType` approach since, according to comments on some SO answers, that approach causes Skype and other non-email clients to match the intent.

Comment: @San I agree. But that's why I posted a comment without pretending to provide an answer. Regards.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is probably that you're running on one of the official Android emulators and you haven't yet set up an email account on it. The emulators open the `com.android.fallback.Fallback` activity when this happens, but this doesn't seem to happen on real-world devices.

You can detect this before trying to start the intent using this code:

```
ComponentName emailApp = intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager());
ComponentName unsupportedAction = ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.fallback/.Fallback");
boolean hasEmailApp = emailApp != null && !emailApp.equals(unsupportedAction);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me :

```
public void addEmail() {

     TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emailtext);

     txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

     public void onClick(View v){

            String[] emails = {"youremail@gmail.com"};
            String subject = "your subject";
            String message = "your message";

            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emails);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

            // need this to prompts email client only
            email.setType("message/rfc822");

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
    }});

}
```

Comment: I've tested and confirmed that this works. Looks like the problem was caused by using `setData()` when no apps match the intent.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is because you havent set up an email account on the emulator. I had the same problem on the emulator but not any more when I tested it on phone.

Comment: This answer simply reiterates what has already been stated in the other answers and comments.