# How to code using android studio to send an email

Tags: android

I'm planning to develop an android mobile  application using android studio, where an user give email address and secret code. Then that secret code should be send to mentioned email address. Can any body share any code snippet in order to do this?

Comment: I think this would answer your question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-can-i-send-emails-from-my-android-application

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want to send email in background refer [here](http://javapapers.com/android/android-email-app-with-gmail-smtp-using-javamail/)

If user is waiting on screen use below method:

```
protected void sendEmail() {
      Log.i("Send email", "");

      String[] TO = {"someone@gmail.com"};
      String[] CC = {"xyz@gmail.com"};
      Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
      emailIntent.setType("text/plain");


      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject");
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message goes here");

      try {
         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
         finish();
         Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
      } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
         "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
   }
```

Comment: I got an error: "The logging tag can be at most 23 characters, was 25 (Finished sending email...) ".

Comment: remove this to resolve the error:

 Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");

Answer (score 7):

If you use Intent.ACTION_SEND android show all communicatons app. If you want show only email client you can use the following code.

```
 Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 Uri data = Uri.parse("mailto:?subject=" + "subject text"+ "&body=" + "body text " + "&to=" + "destination@mail.com");
 mailIntent.setData(data);
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#ComposeEmail

1. Any messaging app:

   ```
    public void composeEmail(String[] addresses, String subject, Uri attachment) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
   ```

   }
2. Only email apps

   ```
   public void composeEmail(String[] addresses) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
   intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
   if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
       startActivity(intent);
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: I think it's the otherway aroud, the 2nd code contains the data as mailto which means it should be sent as an email right?

Comment: 2nd method is not working

Comment: @Eddie, hi, there is an additional step now, please see my other answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62535856/intent-resolveactivity-returns-null-in-api-30/65166064#65166064