# Login Activity - How can I send email to user if they forgot password?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have a small app with a working LoginActivity. I now want to develop a Fragment for this activity that will handle helping the user to create a new password if it has been forgotten. I have seen some people using PHP/MySQL for this, but I was wondering if it is possible to use Java/SQLite to accomplish the same goal?

Expected functionality:

1. User clicks forgot password link
2. Sent to ForgotPass_Fragment which asks/verifies a user's email.
3. If it is a valid email, email the user the code/new temp password

I guess the real question is if I can use Java to send an email to the user with the newly generated info rather than using PHP or some other language? Would [something like this be the best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546703/how-to-code-using-android-studio-to-send-an-email)?

Comment: It is the responsibility of whom you are logging in to on the backend/server side to send the email.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce so would it be considered best practice to handle this sending of the email from intent like in this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546703/how-to-code-using-android-studio-to-send-an-email

Comment: You should call the server side with a REST API call that for example `api/user/forgotPassword` with a JSON like `{ 'email': 'blah@blah.com' }` and the server side should send the recovery email to the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your password recovery information is stored on a server, you will need to use some sort of server-side (PHP, or Java, or whatever) webservice to server the "recovery email".

If for some reason you already have the users password information on the phone (which would be a really bad idea) you could use a local Android Java call to respond with the information.

Bottom line, you will need a webservice to provide the password info the user.

Comment: I am storing in SQLite database for now since we are still in early stages of development. The only time I have the users password/username on the phone is for the SharedPreferences portion to assist the user in staying logged in. Is this ok? If not, what would you recommend?

Comment: SharedPreferences can be easily read by anyone (so is completely un-secure). Outside the scope of this question, but for sure DON'T store secure info in SharedPreferences.

Comment: Okay thanks @Booger . Do you have a suggestion for best practice for staying logged in? ... Also, is it still an issue if I encrypt the info?

Comment: Here is a blog about it: http://www.androidauthority.com/use-android-keystore-store-passwords-sensitive-information-623779/