# How to send email via android app using androis studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm planning to develop an android mobile application using android studio, where i can click on some events on map,i'm done with the events pop-up all i need now is to send the users an email when they click on a button to confirm that they will show up.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: java email api but it's not what i need.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546703/how-to-code-using-android-studio-to-send-an-email

Comment: it works thank you,i appreciate your help really.