# Send order email when submit button clicked

Tags: javascript, android

i am building a simple delivery app, the person writes their order in a text box such as a pickup or a in resturant order, when they press the submit button i want to be notified that i have an order by text or email then i want them to get an email saying the order is recieved how do i do that im new to android studio thanks.

i already have the page and button placed i just want it so when they press the submit button it sends the email/text to them and then it sends me a email with what they typed in the order box.

I have not tried anything yet because i am unsure what to do next.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546703/how-to-code-using-android-studio-to-send-an-email

Comment: @imvain2 is there anything in there so it can also tell me what they typed in the order box so i know what im picking up for them