# Send an email to an address onclick of a button

Tags: java, android, onclick, jakarta-mail

Hi I have got this edit text field, when I click on this button I want what ever is on the edit text box to be emailed to a specific email address. How do I go about doing that ?

```
findViewById(R.id.submit).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto", "email@email.com", null));
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, R.id.feedback_comment);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an Email client :"));
        }
    });
```

as you can see my edit text id is "feedback_comment". And I am passing that in the message.

I would also like to know if there is any way I could send this email in the background so that user doesn't have to see all of this in the front end. You click on the submit button and it sends the email to the specified address without having to play around on sending an email. I had a look at JavaMail and don't know where to start off, please someone help me start off. Thank You

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I send emails from my Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-can-i-send-emails-from-my-android-application)

Comment: How can i get the message that a user has written inside an edit text field ??? how can I send that to my email address onclick of the submit button

Comment: If you don't want to use default mail app on android, you can write your own server side API which will handle things for you.

Answer (score 1):

first in onCreate ..

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id. feedback_comment);
```

then..

```
findViewById(R.id.submit).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "abc@mail.com");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SUBJECT");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, editText.getText().toString().trim());
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an Email client :"));
    }
});
```

Comment: editText will need to be `final` as well if you're going to access it within the onClick() event.

Comment: Thanks for this, I got a rating bar too, how can I show the number of stars been selected and the edit text message at the same time ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use **javaMail** which has been ported to Android.

See more at :

- [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)
- http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android

Hope it can help you.