# How to send mail from Gmail in android?

Tags: android, email, gmail

I am building an android application where an user is required to lo-gin using g+ to enter in the app. After lo-gin there is 3 EditTextView where user enter required data respect to their field to send mail. the field like - recipient mail Id, subject, and body.

Now the problem is How to send the mail to that recipient ID. using my app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I send emails from my Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-can-i-send-emails-from-my-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2197841/3498044

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6264746/3498044

Next time search before you ask

Answer (score 0):

Try with Following

```
private String[] recipients = {"abc@gmail.com"};
private String type = "text/html";

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
intent.setType(type);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail"));
```