# Sending email directly from android application

Tags: email

I'm trying to send email directly from my android app. I've found this [tutorial](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android) and implemented it into my app, but it seems it doesn't work for some reason.

I have INTERNET PERMISSION and I've made *asynctask* for sending, but it still doesn't send any email. I don't have a server, and I don't want to send over intent. I just want this to work like it should with my email client.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I send emails from my Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-can-i-send-emails-from-my-android-application)

Comment: I'd really recommend setting up email capabilities on a server, and using android to pass arguments (message, to, from, etc) to the server via http

Comment: @scubasteve623 I think OP wants to send emails through or like the Android user's email client

Comment: I understand, but still making the case for a different development strategy. By setting up email service on a server, you can reuse it in your iPhone apps, Windows desktop apps, websites, other Android apps, etc all without rewriting code or importing big libraries.