# Intent Email in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

i've got a mess about email intent in Android 4.1.1. here my code:

```
emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "email@gmail.com");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
```

But dialog just showed Bluetooth and Messages app. how can i show email app as in gmail in dialog? Can anyone help me, thanks so much!

Comment: that works for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/2197841/3626214 Check it, use `.setType("message/rfc822")` instead `text/plain`

Comment: I've already found the reason that i met this wrong things. The reason was   u have to set up applications included mail feature in its. I forgot set up one of them. So i've got this mess. thanks everyone helped me !

Answer (score 3):

```
    Intent emailIntent;

    emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:email@gmail.com"));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");

    if (emailIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(emailIntent);
    } else {
        //not_found_email_apps;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void sendEmail() {
  Log.i("Send email", "");
  String[] TO = {""};
  String[] CC = {""};
  Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

  emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
  emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject");
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message goes here");

  try {
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
     finish();
     Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
  }
  catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Above code should work for your query but it's look like you are testing it on **Emulator**, if you testing it on that than make sure any **email client should be present** for sending email, for ex. inbuilt Gmail client on mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

I've already found the reason that i met this wrong things. The reason was u have to set up applications included mail feature in its. I forgot set up one of them. So i've got this mess. thanks everyone helped me !