# on button click send an email to a user in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.1

I am creating an app where I want to implement the forgot password feature, where when a user clicks on a button the user must automatically get an email notification to his device with the credentials inside the mail. I am new to android so could someone help me how I could implement this feature.

Comment: Why will app sends an email to device dude ?? Shouldn't it be the job of server ??? take the user to password recovery screen, let him answer the security question or something like that send that answer to your server, let your server verify it and send the email credentials to user's email account

Comment: Perhaps this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-can-i-send-emails-from-my-android-application