# How to get e-mail attachments in android application?

Tags: android, email, android-intent

Is any way to implement the next scenario?

1. User pushes the button in my application;
2. User chooses application that manages e-mails;
3. User chooses the definite e-mail;
4. My application gets the callback with the attachments from choosen e-mail.

The task is to organize data exchange between my application on different phones.

From phone #1 user #1 sends e-mail with attachment (and this step I have implemented).

Phone #2 has to get e-mail, user #2 has to choose this e-mail, and my application has to handle the attachments from this e-mail.

I'll apritiate for code example.

Comment: Everything should be possible, the only question remain have tried something so far and what was your expectation

Comment: You are right. My expectation is to get the answer with code example, or link to appropriate article.

Comment: I would suggest you to look at implicit intents in Android Programming The big nerd ranch guide 2nd edition chapter 15. you might also look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-can-i-send-emails-from-my-android-application

Comment: Unfortunately, the question from the link is about sending e-mails. I've already done this task. My issue is to get attachments of received e-mail. But I will check the book you recommend. Thanks a lot!

Comment: sorry the book cover only that part of 1, 2, 3 of your question and part 4 is with out attachment, you need to research more regarding the attachment part. your question in general can lead to a little full project and might not be an question, longer.