# Android no apps can perform this action

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclick, email

I have found two threads on the same topic with no solution that I can use, I am looking to click on an email address and automatically open an email app and send email, my code seems fine to me but I get the "No apps can perform this action"

This is the method I am using;

```
 textView_emailid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    textView_emailid.toString(), "your@email.com", null));
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Book an Appointment");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi " + name);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the value of `textView_emailid.toString()`? If the answer is anything other than `mailto`, that would be one problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `intent.setType("text/plain")` to `intent.setType("message/rfc822")`.

Try the code snippet in this post directly without changing anything since it's the correct solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2197841/5250273

If you still get "No apps can perform this action", then your device does not have any email application (since it may be rooted?).

Comment: Hey, that answer seems to be solving that issue, I am looking to automatically read the email address from the emailid string into the recipient text field, any idea?

Comment: `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{textView_emailid.getText().toString()});`

Comment: I am getting a "cannot find method tooString"

Comment: Not tooString(), it is toString().

Comment: That was a typo, I fixed the issue tho thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Change Your Code ACTION_SENDTO to ACTION_SEND
have to sure solve

Comment: u should NOT do that! ACTION_SENDTO guarantees that only email applications can be selected, actionsend show all apps, regatless if they can send the email or not