# Android - How to Get list of Emails that are available in gmail app when i want to enter email id in an edittext?

Tags: android, email, android-edittext

How to Get a list of Emails that are available in Gmail app when i want to enter email id in an edittext?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-can-i-send-emails-from-my-android-application

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this through Edittext, you should use AutoCompleteTextView

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
```

in you Activity File in onCreate

```
    AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView); 

    String selectedEmail;
    List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
    //get runtime permission

    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(YourActivityName.this).getAccounts();

    int i=0;
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
            String possibleEmail = account.name+"\n";
            emails.add(possibleEmail);
        }
    }

   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
   (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,emails);
   autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);

   //default selected email
   selectedEmail = emails.get(0);
   autoComplete.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // You can get the user selected email here    
            String selectedEmail = emails.get(position)
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

in your manifest you need to add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

if you are developing for API>=23(Marshmallow) then you also need to get runtime permissions. Follow this for runtime permissions

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: No  @Shriyansh Gautam. Not Yet.

Comment: This is my edittext                                                                              EditText ed3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);                             String e3 = ed3.getText().toString();                                                                and than your code

Comment: this is not showing any error but it is not working when i click on edittext in my phone.

Comment: it is not working. But can you help me to reach the course to learn Android Validations.Thank YOU.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking at this now this feature with this exact dialog is called Sign in Hints!

https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/retrieve-hints#retrieve_sign-in_hints